# Erro "ConcurrentModificationException" ao modificar (inserir dados no) ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou tentando criar um pequeno sistema de login em Java.

Tenho as seguintes classes:

LoginController:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios = UsuarioController.listaUsuarios;
    // Adiciona um administrador padrao ao ArrayList de Usuarios
    Usuario adminpadrao = new Usuario("Admin", "123456", 1);
    UsuarioController.listaUsuarios.add(adminpadrao);

    String opcao = "";

    while (!opcao.equals("0")) {

        LoginView lv = new LoginView();
        AdminController ac = new AdminController();
        UsuarioController uc = new UsuarioController();

        Usuario u = lv.capturarLogin();
        // Captura o usuario para fazer o login, verifica se ele esta presente no ArrayList e se ele é um administrador. Caso sim, ele vai para o menu de administrador, Caso não, ele vai para o menu de usuario comum
        for (Usuario usuario : listaUsuarios) {
            if (usuario.getUsuario().equals(u.getUsuario()) && usuario.getSenha().equals(u.getSenha())) {
                if (usuario.getAdmin() == 1) {
                    ac.menuAdmin();
                } else {
                    uc.menuUsuario();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AdminController:

```
public class AdminController {

    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    AdminView av = new AdminView();

    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios = UsuarioController.listaUsuarios;

    public void menuAdmin() {

        String opcao = av.exibirMenuAdmin();

        if (opcao.equals("1")) {
            cadastrarUsuario();
        } else if (opcao.equals("2")) {
            listarUsuarios();
        } else if (opcao.equals("3")) {
            excluirUsuario();
        } else if (opcao.equals("4")) {
            Util.continuar();
        }
    }

    public void cadastrarUsuario() {
        Usuario u = av.capturarUsuario();
        listaUsuarios.add(u);
        Util.continuar("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso");
    }

    public void listarUsuarios() {
        av.listarUsuarios(listaUsuarios);
        Util.continuar("Pressione enter para continuar");
    }

    public void excluirUsuario() {
        String u = av.capturarNomeUsuario();

        for (Usuario usuario : listaUsuarios) {
            if (usuario.getUsuario().equals(u)) {
                Util.escreva("Usuario excluido: " + usuario.getUsuario());
                listaUsuarios.remove(usuario);
            } else {
                Util.continuar("Usuario não encontrado");
            }
        }
}
```

Porem, apos eu logar com o administrador padrão e tentar cadastrar um novo usuario, o compilador (Eclipse) retorna o erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at crm.controller.LoginController.main(LoginController.java:27)
```

Essa ultima linha do erro `at crm.controller.LoginController.main(LoginController.java:27)` se refere a linha `for (Usuario usuario : listaUsuarios) {` em LoginController na etapa de verificação do login

Eu acho que seja algum erro no ArrayList. Eu estou tentando usar um único ArrayList para as duas classes.

Queria ajuda para resolver esse erro. Agradeço desde agora.

Comment: Essa exceção ocorre geralmente quando você tenta modificar uma lista ao mesmo tempo em que tenta varre-la com um loop. Mas não está muito claro o motivo do erro nesse código apenas. Dá uma lida [neste link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/concurrentmodificationexception-e-os-fail-fast-iterators/), ele explica as principais causas dessa exceção e como resolver.

Comment: O problema é exatamente o que o Articuno disse. Dentro desse for é chamado o menu Admin que pode pode excluir um utilizador da lista enquanto a mesma esta a ser iterada, gerando a exceção.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações no código e funcionou. Criei um método separado para verificar o usuário/senha com os dados do ArrayList, 
que retorna uma variável do tipo `boolean`. Ao invés de chamar os menus através do `for`, eu fiz um `if` no `main`, que dependendo do resultado da verificação (`true`ou `false`), ele leva para o respectivo menu. Obrigado pela ajuda.